# Mean Field Theory on Random Graphs

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, spin-models, mean-field-theory

We traditionally use mean field theory to analyze graphs with some degree of translation invariance. This assumption of translation invariance enables a key algebraic simplification which makes problems like the ferromagnetic or antiferromagnetic Ising model tractable. In the case of a Ising-type interaction on a random graph, we lose the translation invariance. What insight (if any) does mean field theory provide in this case?

Comment: Somewhat hot subject, but spilling outside of the problems traditionally studied in physics (although still studied by physicists). See, e.g., [Statistical Mechanics of Neural Networks](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-16-7570-6)

Comment: "We traditionally use mean field theory to analyze graphs with some degree of translation invariance." Is there a reference for this?

Answer (score 2):

I got interested in this question too and found a talk that discusses it nicely: https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/crism/workshops/estimatingconstants/mukherjee.pdf

A key aspect of the graph in question (actually a sequence of graphs $G_n$) is how the gap between the largest and second largest eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix scales with $n$. Basically if you can show it grows with $n$, then mean field theory is eventually accurate for very large $n$.

For a sequence of Erdos-Reyni random graphs $G_n$ with $n$ vertices and fixed connectivity parameter $p$, the slides above prove that mean field theory is accurate.